# react native app with expo does not start due to unknow function

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to create and launch React Native App with expo tool and web view.
for that I do :

1. **npx create-react-native app**
2. **cd myProjectApp**
3. **yarn add glob** (because launch yarn web witout this thrown error)
4. **yarn add react-native-web react-dom @expo/webpack-config** (because without this yarn web not running)
5. **yarn web**

Error message : *"TypeError: g.on is not a function"*

full log error :

```
    Starting project at C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest
TypeError: g.on is not a function
TypeError: g.on is not a function
    at C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\glob.js:19:11
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.everyMatchAsync (C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\glob.js:10:12)
    at C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\doctor\typescript\TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite.js:114:24
    at C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\glob.js:56:27
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.wrapGlobWithTimeout (C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\utils\glob.js:49:12)
    at TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite._queryFirstTypeScriptFileAsync (C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\doctor\typescript\TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite.js:113:42)
    at TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite._getSetupRequirements (C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\doctor\typescript\TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite.js:79:43)
    at async TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite.assertImplementation (C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\TEST\secondReactNativeTest\.yarn\cache\@expo-cli-npm-0.7.3-b8fe3aaa8f-f1b03efbec.zip\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\doctor\typescript\TypeScriptProjectPrerequisite.js:50:24)
```

Why I do not have function ?

Why yarn do not tell me to install another package for resolve this missed function ?

What package is missed ?

Comment: Llikely you have some globally installed npm package, the fix would `npm list -g` and so on. `yarn cache clean` also helping at times

Comment: you said you create react native with expo but you running `npx create-react-native app` ?? it should be `npx create-expo-app my-app`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on a non TypeScript project, traced the problem back to this statement in expo cli:

```
await devServerManager.bootstrapTypeScriptAsync();
```

Fixed it by adding the following to my .env:

```
EXPO_NO_TYPESCRIPT_SETUP=1
```